# Freepascal or CodeTyphon: Warnings

Tags: warnings, lazarus, freepascal, codetyphon

Since the compilation of CodeTyphon 64bit, on first use, the ide or compiler throws a couple of warnings, while compiling my programs. Below I detail them.

Compiling project Objective: SGA: Success, Warnings: 2
SGA.lpr (28.1) Warning: "crtbeginS.o" not found, This will probably cause a failure linking
SGA.lpr (28.1) Warning: "crtendS.o" not found, This will probably cause a failure linking

What I can do ?

I might add that seems to work well but my programs so far are very simple. Maybe when complicated give me trouble, I do not know.

It is the same message to the ide installed windows 7 and Linux Mint 18

Greetings and thanks

Comment: Also, see [this fpc FAQ](https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Faq#I_receive_a_warning_during_the_linking_that_states:_Warning:_.22crtbeginS.o.22_.28or_.22crtendS.o.22.29_not_found)

Answer (score 2):

In linux, I got around this error message by adding the path, which contains, crtbeginS.o and crtendS.o, to the fpc.cfg file located in the
/usr/local/codetyphon/fpc/fpc64/bin/x86_64-linux/ folder

I added -Fl/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5 to the library section, where it says '# searchpath for libraries'

Comment: It worked on Fedora 32 too using `-Fl/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10`.

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that the warning appears on windows, since crtbeginS.o is part of Unix startup code, and FPC/Lazarus/CT don't used it on Windows.

As for Linux, probably your system is not prepared for development, install the required packages for development (sometimes there is a meta package for them, try "build-essentials")

If the problems on Windows are while crosscompiling to Linux, it might be a problem with the startup files copied over from the target system. I don't use CT myself, so don't know how that works.